# Let $s=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (\cos(n \pi ))^{n} 3^{-n}$. What is the value of $4s$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have the following question.
Let $s=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (\cos(n \pi ))^{n} 3^{-n}$. What is the value of $4s$ ?

As I understand here this would be the geometric series and its absolute value would be $<1$ so it would converge either towards $\frac{3}{3+1}$ or $\frac{3}{3-1}$ depending on the value of $n$ at the $(cos(n \pi )$. Our solution says only $3/4$ as solution and therefore $4s=3$. How come is the case of $(\cos(n \pi )$ being $-1$ not considered?

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Make cases on n being odd and even and then calculate the sum of geometric series

Answer (score 3):

Since $\cos n\pi=(-1)^n$, $\cos^nn\pi=(-1)^{n^2}=(-1)^n$, so $s=\sum_{n\ge0}(-1/3)^n=\tfrac{1}{1+1/3}=\tfrac34$.